# Usage of USERELATIONSHIP function

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

[image]We use a report that makes a reference (via active table relationship) to a specific table. It is necessary to deactivate this relationship to properly calculate a value in a visual.  However, when I deactivate this relationship it causes MANY (near 100) other items to break.  I am able to apply formula fixes to these "broken" visuals by using the USERELATIONSHIP function.

My question is "In place of changing formulas in many places, Is there an ANTI version (or usage) of USERELATIONSHIP that I only apply in one location to apply a fix to a single visual)

I've tried to create a table that includes the matching date values that are related and that does mitigate my issue.

Additionally, this project has patient health information and I wouldn't be able to share a version of the file.

```
    MJLT Total Lives = 
    CALCULATE(COUNT(Lives[mem_id1])
    ,
        Filter (Lives,
                    (
                        Lives[meme_eff] <= MAX('Calendar'[Date])
                        &&
                        Lives[clip_eff] <= MAX('Calendar'[Date])
                        &&
                        Lives[meme_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                        &&
                        Lives[clip_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                        &&
                        Lives[cli_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                        &&
                        Lives[meme_eff] <= Lives[meme_trm])
                )
            ) +0
```

```
{MJLT Total Lives = 
CALCULATE(COUNT(Lives[mem_id1])
,
ALL(lives)
,
all(Claims)
,
ALL(ClientIDs)
,
all('Calendar')

,
    Filter (Lives,
                (
                    Lives[meme_eff] <= MAX('Calendar'[Date])
                    &&
                    Lives[clip_eff] <= MAX('Calendar'[Date])
                    &&
                    Lives[meme_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                    &&
                    Lives[clip_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                    &&
                    Lives[cli_trm] >= min('Calendar'[Date])
                    &&
                    Lives[meme_eff] <= Lives[meme_trm])
            )
        ) +0
```

Comment: you can "deactivate"  any relationships by using ALL function (ALL(Table)  clears all filters  coming from the table).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'm investigating how to apply this.  I believe I can fix this if I'm able to determine what the "relationship" is when I deactivate a table relationship in the relationship editor. Then I can reactivate the table relationship and explicitly express the relationship for the problematic measure using the USERELATIONSHIP function.  So... is there a way to authoritatively determine the relationship used by a measure?

Comment: by default, there is always only one active relationship, and that's what is used in measures. All other relations are inactive and don't affect anything unless you explicitly involve them with USERELATIONSHIPS

Comment: The count values are accurate when the relationship is set to inactive, however, as said before this "break " in relationship wrecks other measures, as I look at the measure added above, I don't understand what is "removed" when deactivating the RELATIONSHIP.  If I know I can set the explicit relationship in the USERELATIONSHIP function.